# Scala - merge a list to map

Tags: scala, rdd

I need to merge a list into a set from an `RDD`, but I got stuck doing it in Scala:

```
var accounts = set("name" -> "", "id" -> 0, ....)

//Split the RDD into lines and split each line by `|` to get the values
stream.foreachRDD {_.map(_._2).flatMap(_.split("|")).foreach(f => /*merge here ?*/)}
```

How do I associate the values with my account sets?

For example, assume a RDD loaded from a CSV (I made up this data)

```
 Donald|Trump|US|Election|March|Spring|Rubio|Ted Cruz|Ben Carson|Primary|Winner|...
 Donald|Trump|US|Election|March|Spring|Rubio|Ted Cruz|Ben Carson|Primary|Winner|...
 Donald|Trump|US|Election|March|Spring|Rubio|Ted Cruz|Ben Carson|Primary|Winner|...
 Donald|Trump|US|Election|March|Spring|Rubio|Ted Cruz|Ben Carson|Primary|Winner|...
 Donald|Trump|US|Election|March|Spring|Rubio|Ted Cruz|Ben Carson|Primary|Winner|...
 Donald|Trump|US|Election|March|Spring|Rubio|Ted Cruz|Ben Carson|Primary|Winner|...
 Donald|Trump|US|Election|March|Spring|Rubio|Ted Cruz|Ben Carson|Primary|Winner|...
 ...
```

The RDD has up to 300 columns/fields.

My main objective is to convert it to some json but I need to associate each value to a key by loading it up to map or class.

```
var election = Map ("firstname" -> "Donald",
"lastname" -> "Trump",
"country" -> "US",
"event" -> "Election",
"period" -> "March"
"var1" -> "Spring",
 ....
"varN" -> "...")
```

Comment: I would like to help you, but I have no idea what you need. Provide some code with mock data and remove the Spark dependencies. E.g. "I have this list <insert list example here> and I want to transform it into this set <insert set example here>. I have no idea what kind of data you have, how is it formatted, what do you get when you split by "|" and what you need to do with it.

Comment: @slouc - I just included an example, please check it out. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly, but does this help?

```
val data = List(
  "Donald|Trump|US|Election|March",
  "John|Smith|UK|Election|February"
)

val mapKeys = List("firstname", "lastname", "country", "event", "period")

val election = data.map { row =>
  (mapKeys zip row.split("\\|").toList).map {
    case (key, value) => key -> value
  }.toMap
}
```

So, you will get a list of maps - for each row of your data you get a map of key/value pairs as you described.

Comment: @sloc - Nice! I will give it a shot...makes sense. Another options am thinking of right now, maybe I could create an RDD from `data` and union it with existing RDD and use a native function to convert the RDD to json ?

Answer (score 0):

A bit of clean up to @slouc answer

```
stream.foreachRDD {_.map(_._2).map(l => (mapKeys zip l.split("\\|")).toMap).saveToEs(conf)}
```